# Difference between Python on VSCode vs PyChamp or Console Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, arguments, argparse

A little bit of context...I'm new to python so, Since I am new to the language I've started by googling the best IDE to use with python, many sites recommended Pycharm so I started using it, But since I use VSCode at work I decided to try it but I've experienced some issues with it, and for that reason I not able to use it at the moment. Let me explain maybe someone knows the reason of a possible solution.

I'm currently running Python 3.10.2

In one of my script I use argparse to receive serval execution parameters, in particular a parameter called "FILTER" so in argparse I have defined this parameter as follows:

```
parser.add_argument('-f', '-filter', '-F', '--FILTER', dest='filter', action='append',
                    help='Apply column filters according to the operator en value provided')
```

Basically the idea is to receive a, NAME, OPERATOR and VALUE to filter. ie.

```
-f TERM_LN!=PLUSS (this works fine in both IDE and python console)
-f CRNCY_CDE=032 (this works fine in both IDE and python console)
-f AMOUNT>=0,02 (this only works on PyCharm and console BUT not in VSCode)
```

By debugging the script I've noticed that **argparse.parse_args()** function returns the **AMOUNT** filter as follows... **filter:[' AMOUNT,02']** in **VSCode** (Incorrect) whereas on the **Python console** or **PyCharm** I see it like **[' AMOUNT>=0,02']** (Correct)

Just as a side note, when I invoke the script form the console I pass the argument like this...

```
(venv) C:\dev\PythonProjects\PyAuthomation\venv\Scripts>python ../../generator.py "-f AMOUNT>=0,02" ../../Info.xls --VERBOSE (Verbose is only for getting diagnostics info of the running script)
```

From Pycharm I've configured the parameters for the script from the option Run -> Edit Configurations... in the parameter option I introduced

```
"-f AMOUNT>=0,02" Info.xls --VERBOSE
```

From VSCode from what I've found on the internet the way to provided the parameter for the execution of the python script is by creating the file "Launch.json".

This is my actual configuration...

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "-f AMOUNT>=0,02",
                "INFO.xls",
                "--VERBOSE"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I've also noticed that Console or Pycharm only returns the actual parameter value whereas VSCode also return SPACE character between the -f and the Name of the filter as if the space char was part of the actual parameter name, even though I was not expecting that it's easy to solve.

On the other hand, the issue with the ">=" it's not. I have no idea what's the correct way to configure VSCode to accept such types of parameters   as plain text just like the PyCharm or the Python console does, It seems that some kind of parsing is causing the issue, but I have no idea Why or any possible workaround for it.

One additional note if I change the ">=" for "=" everything works as expected.

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: Which shell is the VSCode terminal using? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal

Comment: Look at `sys.argv`.  That's what `argparse` reads.

Comment: `>` is file redirection, try `-f "AMOUNT>=0,02"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with arguments containing `<` and `>` is `cmd`.

The Python extension passes a command to `cmd` in a string

```
cd <somedir> && cmd /C "bit debug command with parameters"
```

`cmd` somehow removes the `<` and `>` and makes it file redirections for stdin and stdout. I have not found a way to escape the `>` to prevent `cmd` from removing it when passed with `/C`.

The solution is to use a task to start the debugger and attach VSC to this debugger. In the task you can add `"` to prevent the shell `cmd` to process the `>` as a file redirect.

What to do is explained in: [How do I redirect input and output in VSC python code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70488390/9938317) to find the text needed for the `<path>` part in `task.json`, and you might need to change the extension name `ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655`

For your case I use the following

**task.json**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Script for filter",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${command:python.interpreterPath} <path>\\.vscode\\extensions\\ms-python.python-2021.12.1559732655\\pythonFiles\\lib\\python\\debugpy --listen 5678 --wait-for-client ${file} -f \"AMOUNT>=0,02\""
      "problemMatcher": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Watch the passing of the argument `-f \"AMOUNT>=0,02\"`. You have to add `"` to prevent the terminal shell/cmd to create a file redirect. You have to escape the `"` inside a JSON string.

**launch.json**

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Python: Attach to Process port 5678",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "attach",
      "connect": {
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": 5678
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "Python: Start Process port 5678",
      "type": "python",
      "request": "launch",
      "code": "print()",
      "preLaunchTask": "Script for filter"
    }
  ],
  "compounds": [
    {
      "name": "Debug filter",
      "configurations": [
        "Python: Start Process port 5678",
        "Python: Attach to Process port 5678"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Select `Debug filter` in the debug bar and start the debug session.

---

**Edit**

Just found out that if you use Powershell as your [integrated terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) the command arguments all get surrounded with `'`

You only have to split the `-f AMOUNT>=0,02` in 2 elements of the `args` array to make sure they are passed as 2 separate arguments.

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": [
                "-f",
                "AMOUNT>=0,02",
                "INFO.xls",
                "--VERBOSE"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Gatunox See my edit, switching to Powershell solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problems aren't with `argparse`, but with how the various inputs are "split" by the shell or ide.

I have a simple script that echos the `sys.argv` list that `argparse` works with:

```
0012:~/mypy$ cat echo.py
import sys
print(sys.argv)
```

Just using a linux terminal window (console)

```
0012:~/mypy$ python3 echo.py -f TERM_LN!=PLUSS
['echo.py', '-f', 'TERM_LN!=PLUSS']

0014:~/mypy$ python3 echo.py -f CRNCY_CDE=032
['echo.py', '-f', 'CRNCY_CDE=032']

0014:~/mypy$ python3 echo.py -f AMOUNT>=0,02
0015:~/mypy$ ls =* 
'=0,02'
0015:~/mypy$ cat =0,02
['echo.py', '-f', 'AMOUNT']
```

The last redirected the output to a file1 because of how the shell interpreted the '>'

quoting to block the redirect.  This is often needed in shell to block special character handling:

```
0018:~/mypy$ python3 echo.py -f "AMOUNT>=0,02"
['echo.py', '-f', 'AMOUNT>=0,02']
```

Notice in all of these the '-f' is a separate string.  So your `json` probably should be:

```
        "args": [
            "-f",
            "AMOUNT>=0,02",
            "INFO.xls",
            "--VERBOSE"
            ]
```

### edit

I'm not quite sure what you mean by 'python console', but since I usually use `ipython` to test and demonstrate code, I can run a script with it's `%run` magic.

```
0845:~/mypy$ ipython3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Nov 26 2021, 20:14:08) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.0.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: %run echo.py -f AMOUNT>=0,02
['echo.py', '-f', 'AMOUNT>=0,02']
```

That is not using the `bash` shell, so doesn't redirect.

Using its shell magic I need the quotes:

```
In [4]: !python3 echo.py -f "AMOUNT>=0,02"
['echo.py', '-f', 'AMOUNT>=0,02']
```

I use `ipython` "straight", but judging from other SO questions, people use in other IDEs, such as `spyder`.  I haven't paid attention to those details.  I use `Geany` as my main script editor.  You'll also see a lot of `Jupyter` use, which includes `ipython`, and browser based `notebooks`.

Since you are (apparently) using Windows, your shell interactions may be different.

Comment: this is not the solution, on Windows the whole command is passes to `cmd` as one string inside `"`, somehow `cmd` filters out the `>=0` and creates a file redirect to a file named `0`

Comment: Yes, I see that file created on the folder, but why it's not the case on Pycharm of Python console, they skip the use of the cmd?

Comment: @Gatunox they probably call a system exec call to start a new process and they handle stdin and stdout and show it in the GUI

Comment: I added a couple of `ipython` examples, which may shed light on your 'python console' case.